# Can iPhone 6S run iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, ios8

My app supports iOS 8 to 9. A user told me that the app keeps freezing on his iPhone 6S running iOS 8. As seen from Apple's spec, 6S only supports iOS 9 and Xcode does not have an iPhone 6S iOS 8 simulator. Officially, can iOS 8 run on iPhone 6S?

Answer (score 1):

It can't, the user probably owns an iPhone 6 or 6 plus.

Comment: How about unofficial ways such as jailbreak? I am not familiar with jailbreak things. Thank you.

Comment: There is no known /public/ exploit in the bootloader to do that. Event if somebody have it, its still impossible to install iOS to any unsupported device. its not open source like Android to fix driver issues and go on.
I can't go any further into this, but you can 100% sure that your user is either running iOS 9.x and up, or have an older iPhone